# In which episode did Debra find out about Dexter's brother?

Tags: dexter

In the show Dexter, season 6 episode 4, when Dexter Morgen walks into the crime scene with the two corpse horsemen, Dexter says "this spectacle makes me think of..." and Debra finishes the sentence "your brother... Rudy, the Ice Truck killer...".

When exactly did Debra find this out, as I don't remember any reference prior to this where Dexter has specifically stated that Rudy was his brother?

Comment: Note that Rudy's real name (in the show) is Brian Moser.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happened **at the end of *Season 4*** ([***The Getaway***](http://dexter.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_412:_The_Getaway)):

> **Debra finds out the truth about [Dexter's mother](http://dexter.wikia.com/wiki/Laura_Moser), and tells him that she knows that Dexter's brother was the *Ice Truck Killer***.
>
> Dexter pretended this news was new to him and acted surprised. He is now concerned that Debra is getting closer to finding the truth about him, which gives him more of a reason to change his life.